# How to post the name or id of a textbox, like the way we post the value of it

Tags: php, html

I have two textboxes called `text1` and `text2`, and variables `value1` and `value2`.

When the user submits the form, I want to create a url like below

```
mydomain.com/?text1=value1&text2=value2
```

How can I pass the name of the texbox or a dropdown list?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: What do you want me to post, a html form and a php one that gets the values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you know how to use [$_GET](http://phpstreet.blogspot.com/2007/05/php-get-variable.html). If not, you [need to learn about the difference](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/methods.html) between `get` and `post`.

Otherwise, if you really *must* use $_POST, you can use [http_build_query()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) or if it's not available, something like this after the form submit:

```
$url = '?';
foreach ($_POST as $k => $v)
{
     $url .= "&".urlencode($k).'='.urlencode($v);
}
header("Location: mydomain.com/$url");
```

The most sensible solution is to use $_GET, which will do this for you automatically.

```
<form method="get" action="mydomain.com">
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understood your question, you should set the method attribute in your form to "get". Once the form is submitted you'll see the form fields' submitted values in the url.